# Counting the number of conjugacy classes of group of order 625

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

How to count number of conjugacy classes in a group of order 625? I am only able to see when group is abelian. But in case of non-abelian I am unable to say anything. Thank you for help.

Comment: See whether this helps you:http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_groups_of_prime-fourth_order

Comment: @Rohan: I looked at it but found no satisfactory arguments

Comment: @SubhashChandBhoria Since $625=5^4$, this page contains the answer to your question.